# Google Analytics API Bad Gateway 502 Errors

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

We are collecting Google Analytics data off of the GA API for various accounts. In most instances it works without a problem, but for one account we keep getting an unknown 502 error with the following response:

```
<p><b>502.</b> <ins>That's an error.</ins>\n  <p>The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That's all we know.</ins>\n"enter code here
```

Once we hit 10 of these (as per the error limit) we are kicked into 429s because we've reached our error quota limit.

There is no proxy in (except ostensibly on the GA side) between us and this works without problem for most accounts but this one.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a [bug](https://developers.google.com/analytics/help/#bugs) that should be sent to the [issues tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187400).

There are a few bugs [open bugs](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:187400%20502) that are about 502 errors as well. Your issue may be the same as one of these.